# Can you decompile Actionscript 3 on a Mac?

Tags: decompilation, swf, actionscript, osx

Reverse engineering `SWFs` with `ActionScript 3` on a Mac typically requires a *Windows VM* and a lot of copying and pasting. There are some good decompilers for Windows such as [as3extractor](https://sites.google.com/site/as3extractor/) but I haven't found anything that seems to work on MacOS X.

Does a functional equivalent to `as3extractor` exist for Mac OS X ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a [blog URL](http://bruce-lab.blogspot.com/2010/08/freeswfdecompilers.html) that lists free SWF Decompilers available. It includes programs for decompiling AS2 & AS3.

Some of the tools listed there include:

- ActionScript Extractor
- SWFWire Decompiler
- JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler
- JP ActionScript decompiler (ASDec)
- HP SWFScan, etc.

If you want to disassemble AS3, then I highly recommend `SWFDump`.

**`swfdump`** (part of **`SWFTools`** package) will decompile AS3 and will work in Mac as long as you follow the instructions in their [FAQ](http://www.swftools.org/faq.html) to compile the tool set for Mac.

The current collection is comprised of the programs detailed below:

- **`SWFDump`** Prints out various informations about SWFs, like contained images/fonts/sounds, disassembly of contained code as well as cross-reference and bounding box data.
- **`SWFStrings`** Scans SWFs for text data.
- **`SWFC`** A tool for creating SWF files from simple script files. Includes support for both - ActionScript 2.0 as well as ActionScript 3.0.
- **`SWFExtract`** Allows to extract Movieclips, Sounds, Images etc. from SWF files.
- **`AS3Compile`** A standalone ActionScript 3.0 compiler. Mostly compatible with Flex.
- **`SWFCombine`** A multi-function tool for inserting SWFs into Wrapper SWFs, contatenating SWFs, stacking SWFs or for basic parameter manipulation (e.g. changing size).
- **`PDF2SWF`** A PDF to SWF Converter. Generates one frame per page. Enables you to have fully formatted text, including tables, formulas, graphics etc. inside your Flash Movie. It's based on the `xpdf` PDF parser from Derek B. Noonburg.
- **`JPEG2SWF`** Takes one or more JPEG pictures and generates a SWF slideshow from them. Supports motion estimation compression (h.263) for better compression of video sequences.
- **`PNG2SWF`** Like `JPEG2SWF`, only for PNGs.
- **`GIF2SWF`** Converts GIFs to SWF. Also able to handle animated gifs.
- **`WAV2SWF`** Converts WAV audio files to SWFs, using the L.A.M.E. MP3 encoder library.
- **`AVI2SWF`** Converts AVI animation files to SWF. It supports Flash MX H.263 compression. Some examples can be found at examples.html. (Notice: this tool is not included anymore in the latest version, as ffmpeg or mencoder do a better job nowadays)
- **`Font2SWF`** Converts font files (TTF, Type1) to SWF.
- **`SWFBBox`** Allows to read out, optimize and readjust SWF bounding boxes.

**`SWFTools`** has been reported to work on Solaris, Linux (both 32 as well as 64 bit), FreeBSD, OpenBSD, HP-UX, Solaris, MacOS X and Windows 98/ME/2000/XP/Vista.

Comment: I used to like [Flasm](http://www.nowrap.de/flasm.html) but it is outdated. If you don't have other options you should check it too.

Comment: Yes, I do agree that Flasm is outdated which is why I am recommending SWFTools.

Comment: does SWFDump decompile (bytecode) or disassemble (high level syntax) ?

Comment: ange, you are correct. SWFDump disassembles AS3. I have updated the answer to include the list of free decompilers.

Comment: @rev is there a way to re-assemble that bytecode after it's been disassembled via swfdump? I'm reading the manpages but feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: I am trying to disassemble code using swfdump, but can't find an option to get code…

Answer (score 5):

**Commercial:**

If you're alright with commercial tools, Sothink's SWF decompiler for Mac should be capable of decompiling AS3 on Mac. I've only used the Windows version but I believe their features should be mostly similar. They have a feature to export FLA from a SWF file which works very well for most cases.

Their product page mentions

> Support Flash CS3/CS4/CS5/CS5.5/CS6 and ActionScript 2.0/3.0.

http://www.sothink.com/product/flash-decompiler-for-mac/

**Freeware:**

I do not know of a good freeware solution. If you'd like to use AS3Extractor on your Mac, you can consider running Wine (install via [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew)). AS3Extractor also mentions that they have a dependency on [Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en) so do take note!

Answer (score 1):

I use https://www.free-decompiler.com/flash/ which is the best software I have seen. It has almost all features you can want. It also comes with a java library which can be handy to automate your workflow.

For a more low-level tool : https://github.com/CyberShadow/RABCDAsm